# Whats the correct way to write

Tags: javascript

```
for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    str += "<span class='ecolor' style='background-color:'" + colors[i] + "' title='" + colors[i] + "'></span>";
}
```

whats the correct order to write `style='background-color:'" + colors[i] + "'`

so it renders properly with background color. Currently its not working`

Comment: There is no content in the span?

Comment: ya i just want to show a square with background color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You close background-color just after colon:

not

```
str += "<span class='ecolor' style='background-color:'" + colors[i] +
```

but

```
str += "<span class='ecolor' style='background-color:" + colors[i] +
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 str += "<span class='ecolor' style='background-color:'" + colors[i] + "' title='" + colors[i] + "'></span>";
```

This will make something like:

```
<span class='ecolor' style='background-color:'red' title='red'></span>
```

Note the extra quote between `:` and `r`.

```
 str += "<span class='ecolor' style='background-color: " + colors[i] + "' title='" + colors[i] + "'></span>";
```

Comment: You're too fast :) I was wondering how everyone else could overlook this.

Comment: @Armatus I actually only noticed it because single quotes in HTML tags make me cringe.  They stand out to me, so I guess that worked well in this case haha.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in your span, it's an inline element so will reduce to nothing. without content or the proper styling.

Do you have any styling on it?
And what's in the `colors` array?

Comment: colors array contains the color like red, #ffeeff .. etc and i want to know how to write style='background-color:'" + colors[i] + "' so it renders properly currently it renders like style="background-color:" red'

Comment: so that`s why bgcolor is not comes

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because of no input inside the span to give it a width:

You could just insert a space:

```
for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    str += "<span class='ecolor' style='background-color:'" + colors[i] + "' title='" + colors[i] + "'> &nbsp;</span>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hy

The code should look like

```
for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    str += "<span class=\"ecolor\" style=\"background-color:" + colors[i] + "\" title=\"" + colors[i] + "\"></span>";
}
```